# How to create a custom language parser for NetBeans?

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans, antlr, rhino

I made a custom interpreter to write server-side code in javascript embedded in HTML, much like PHP, except for the actual programming language. It is implemented as a Servlet that parses Javascript using Rhino.

The pages are defined as:

```
<% 
// Javascript code
var world = "World"; 
%>
<html>
<body>
    <!-- the following code is a javascript expression  -->
    Hello <%= world %> 
</body>
</html>
```

How could I build support for this language into NetBeans? I see that NetBeans already parses HTML and Javascript perfectly. Is it possible to reuse/combine Netbeans' HTML+JS functionality to parse & highlight these pages?

Comment: Have you been able to implement this? I'm currently thinking about a similar issue and I don't want to start from scratch creating a new language - as it is, NB already deals with JS and HTML, so I'd like to tweak its parser a little, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refer to the Netbeans WIKI "How to create support for a new language" here:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/How_to_create_support_for_a_new_language

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Will look into these tutorials. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Glad to have helped. Please consider accepting my answer. Thank  you :)